# Reading URL from JSON file using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, json

How to fetch URL stored in json file using angularjs?

JSON File

```
"Media": [
        {
          "title": "Example_1",
          "url": "http://www.example.com/example.jpg"
        },
        {
          "title": "Example_2",
          "url": "http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4"
        }
]
```

I want to use the 'url' in `<img>`, `<video>` tags!

In HTML,

I tried

```
<img src="{{media.url}}"></img>
```

But nothing happens? Am I missing something?

Comment: have you tried to use ng-src?

Comment: you have an array of JSON objects there, so you'll need to fetch each record with something like images[0].title, images[0].url, images[1].title, images[1].url. Or use `.each()` to iterate your JSON array.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `ng-src`?

```
<img ng-src="{{image.url}}"></img>
```

For videos there are many work arounds but here is one example.

Inject the $sce provider into your controller and use the $sce.trustAsResourceUrl method to set the videoUrl.

```
function MyControl($scope, $sce) {
    var videoUrl = 'http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4';
    $scope.videoUrl = $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(videoUrl);
}
```

Then in your view

```
<video ng-src="{{videoUrl}}" controls></video>
```

Another work around is creating a filter

```
filter("trustUrl", ['$sce', function($sce) {
  return function(videoUrl) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(videoUrl);
  };
}]);
```

And then in your view

```
<video src="{{Your_URL | trustUrl}}" controls></video>
```

Comment: ng-src works on img! Thanks. But on <video width="240" controls><source src="{{video.url}}" type="video/mp4"></video> ng-src doesnt work

Comment: Hi i've updated my answer! If this helped you out don't forget to accept the answer :)

Comment: Hi, I have edited my json file. If json contains url to server location!  <video width="240" controls><source src="{{video.url}}" type="video/mp4"></video> doesnt work!